# How to diagram automated testing?

Tags: testing, diagrams

I have a large legacy .NET application that has evolved and grown over the years to include many components and moving parts. I want to develop a strategy for developing automated unit and integration tests for this application and to that end I think a graphical representation would be key.

What I am picturing is some sort of diagram I could use to guide the process of writing up the test cases, help achieve better coverage, and eventually refer back to once a specific test fails. Does anyone have any thoughts on what type of diagram could fulfill this goal? My guess is this would be a variant of the classic functional block diagram, but I have not found examples that specifically relate to the design of an automated testing strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be what you are looking for?

> The UTP provides extensions to UML to
>   support the design, visualization,
>   specification, analysis, construction,
>   and documentation of the artifacts
>   involved in testing.  It is
>   independent of implementation
>   languages and technologies, and can be
>   applied in a variety of domains of
>   development.

UML Testing Profile: http://utp.omg.org/